# I'm trying to create a tkinter (python 3) application on raspbian, but won't repeat drawing

Tags: python, tkinter, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

My code is as below; it should draw random colour and  size circles repeatedly, but only draws one. I have tried countless combinations of mainloop() and window1.update() but always have the same problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from tkinter import *
from random import *
WIDTH = 1024/2
HEIGHT = 720/2
window1 = Tk()
c1 = Canvas(window1, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg='#FFFFFF')
c1.pack()
colours = ('#FF0000', '#00FF00', '#0000FF', '#FFFF00', '#FF00FF')
while 3 == 3:
    colchose = choice(colours)
    x0 = randint(0, WIDTH)
    y0 = randint(0, HEIGHT)
    c1.create_oval(x0, y0, x0+d, y0+d, fill=colchose)
    mainloop()
```

Comment: Unrelated, but what is `d` exactly? It is not defined in your snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your mainloop() call in the last line. This call will end, once the whole program has terminated.
I would suggest you to look at the [threading facilities](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/threading.html) of Python. You could create another thread that draws onto the canvas while the mainloop is executing.